# How to time-indexed the ros output txt file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

Im using ROS Fuerte and Ubuntu 10.4. Would like to have some outputs of my nodes as a text file. Is there any option to time indexed those outputs?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46051/how-to-time-indexed-the-ros-output-txt-file/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rostopic echo /data > data.txt

---

Originally posted by [Zargol](https://answers.ros.org/users/6711/zargol/) with karma: 206 on 2014-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the [ROS Logging mechanism](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Logging) for that. Just output what you're interested in using the ROS_INFO or ROS_DEBUG mechanisms and record /rosout using rosbag, e.g.

```
rosbag record /rosout
```

you can then later play back all data with timestamps provided, and view them for example using [rxconsole](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rxconsole).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-10-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-10-17**:
But I meaned something else. I have some outputs like velocitiy and diestance saves in txt file. So using my file option and my file open can the ouptuts parameters like velocity and distance saved in a txt file. My question is hot to time-indexed that output txt file. Understand?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-10-17**:
You can use the same. Just record the textual program output instead of a bag.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-10-17**:
So I record the textual program using rosbag record/ output.txt. Yes?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-10-17**:
rosbag record records the messages in binary format. Just record your binaries raw text output as you would with any non-ros program, i.e. my_node > output.txt.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-10-17**:
and  how  to play back the output data with timestamps provided?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-10-17**:
In that case you need a logfile.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-10-17**:
So will use the ros logging mechanism??